# How to speed up the connection to IP camera in Android app?

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, rtsp, ip-camera

I'm developing an Android app (Android 5.1) for playing the video stream from IP camera using the RTSP protocol.

I receive and display video stream using the Android `VideoView`'s standard methods:

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.1.13:8888/test"));
try {
 videoView.start();
 }
catch (Exception ex) {
 ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Everything works fine, but the connection to the camera takes too long. 
It takes about 5-7 seconds (too long for my needs) before video starts playing.

Is there any way to speed up the connection time?

Comment: Do you mean that making the connection takes that long, or is there a delay of the playback that big?

Comment: @n247s Exactly making the connection. Playback has no delay.

Comment: The connection has to be made nontheless. So I guese you can't bypass the connection delay at all. Only thing you might be able to do is maintaining the resource/connection so that reactivating doesnt take that long. (propably accomplished with `VideoView#suspend()`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution.
The problem was that Android' `MediaPlayer`, that is a part of `VideoView`, has fixed buffer size that cannot be changed.
So i used Google' `ExoPlayer`, which provides such feature.
Making buffer size smaller resolved my problem.

P.S.
Maintaining the resource/connection with `VideoView.suspend()` or `VideoView.pause()` to resume stream later doesn't make a thing.